# Android Google Tag Manager does not work

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I'm having trouble while implemented the new google tag manager lib.

Here is what I did:

- I create a macro dataleyr
- I set a rule for an event
- I create a tag and set the universal analytics ID on it
- I publish my container

Then I tried to use it in my app like this

```
TagManager mTagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);

DataLayer mDataLayer = com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManager.getInstance(this).getDataLayer();

ContainerOpener.openContainer(
    mTagManager, CONTAINER_ID, OpenType.PREFER_NON_DEFAULT,
    TIMEOUT_FOR_CONTAINER_OPEN_MILLISECONDS, new ContainerOpener.Notifier() {

        @Override
        public void containerAvailable(Container container) {
            container.refresh();
            // Save container for use by any other activities in the app.
            com.appsconceptelite.appsconceptelite.testfunctionnalities.gtm.ContainerHolder.setContainer(container);

            mContainer = com.appsconceptelite.appsconceptelite.testfunctionnalities.gtm.ContainerHolder.getContainer();

            Utils.pushOpenScreenEvent(LearnActivity.this, "Learn Screen");
        }
    });
```

and the method I use to push event is

```
/**
 * Push an "openScreen" event with the given screen name. Tags that match that event will fire.
 */
public static void pushOpenScreenEvent(Context context, String screenName) {

    DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer();

    dataLayer.pushEvent("openScreen", DataLayer.mapOf("screenName", screenName));
}
```

When I run this code in debug mode, I get the right container name and version but when I check in Google Analytics dashbord, I see no events like if no data have been pushed.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find any luck with GTM for Android

Comment: Hi Pang,

Your code only sends data (and event) to the Google Tag Manager. Please check your GTM logic (rule) to make sure data will be sent

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will solve the issue but what tripped me is the old google analytics account that hasn't been created a "Mobile apps" account and no results would be seen on the account but were definitely sent out. Create a new "Mobile apps" property and try again.

Comment: I created a mobile app but also having the same problem